# Point to site VPN connection between a azure web site and classic virtual network using powershell

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to create a point to site VPN connection between a web app and a classic VNET. I am trying to see if there is way to automate this using a powershell. But the resources seem to be scarce. Any pointers on this would be helpful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your description,  you want to integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network. Am I right?

You could connect your app to your to your classic virtual network by using PowerShell. **Connect your app to a preexisting virtual network that has a gateway and is configured for point-to-site connectivity.**

To connect an app to a virtual network, follow these three steps:

1. Declare to the web app that it will be joining a particular virtual network. The app will generate a certificate that will be given to the virtual network for point-to-site connectivity.
2. Upload the web app certificate to the virtual network, and then retrieve the point-to-site VPN package URI.
3. Update the web app's virtual network connection with the point-to-site package URI.

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-vnet-integration-powershell#classic-virtual-networks).

Also, you could do it on Azure Portal. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#enabling-vnet-integration).

Notes:To enable integration simply click on the VNET you wish to integrate with. **After you select the VNET, your app will be automatically restarted for the changes to take effect.**

Comment: Thank you for that. But does the powershell commands in the link shared by you work for "Classic" vnets too? The powershell commands seem to be ARM commands. Portal is an easy and tried and tested way. But i am looking to automate that process

Comment: Yes, this works for "Classic" Vnet. Based on my experience, portal is more easier way. It is complicated for you to achieve your scenario by using powershell.

Comment: @HariSubramaniam You could use the ARM cmdlet to connect classic net and your webapp

Comment: Thank you. I havent tried it yet though. Doing a bit of research on what powershell commands could help. i will  update here post that. Thanks pointing in the right direction